# Automatic backup/restore at start server

Tags: iccube

I would like an automatic backup of a schema to a file on every load and at a restart of icCube an automatic restore of the last backup. And of course an automatic cleanup of those files. This way we would have a lot less downtime on a restart.

It looks like icCube has that with backup and/or offline data, but I can't get that working like I described above. Is what I want possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the backup in the schema file (Advanced Properties).

Now everytime you load the schema it will create a backup.

And if you set "Load On Startup" as well, icCube is going to load the last backup available.

There is no automatic cleanup: for that purpose you can use the [Rest API](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/api/requests.php) available in the latest icCube. Otherwise, you can cleanup yourself the backup files created in the ~/icCube-data/backup folder.

Hope that helps.

Comment: We had problems with "load on startup" therefor I was only looking in the scheduler. But those problems were long time ago, will give it a try. Thanks.